# ¿Cómo desanidar condicionales en Python?

Tags: python, condiciones

Supongamos una función (o bloque condicional) como ésta:

```
def es_triangulo_equilatero(lado1, lado2, lado3, angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
    if tres_lados_iguales(lado1, lado2, lado3):
        if tres_angulos_iguales(angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Qusiera saber si en todas las funciones en las que se exige el cumplimiento de **varias** condiciones, se tiene que anidar siempre una condición dentro de la otra, e indicar lo que tiene que ocurrir en los casos negativos de manera exhaustiva, o por el contrario existe alguna sintaxis más limpia que valide o revoque el cumplimiento de todas las condiciones al mismo tiempo.

He estado buscando en SO y otros sitios pero no parece haber demasiada información al respecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escribir algo como:

```
if condicion:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

es un *antipatrón*, puesto que de forma mucho más sucinta puedes hacer:

```
return condicion
```

En tu caso:

```
def es_triangulo_equilatero(lado1, lado2, lado3, angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
    return (tres_lados_iguales(lado1, lado2, lado3) 
            and tres_angulos_iguales(angulo1, angulo2, angulo3))
```

En realidad ni siquiera necesitas esas funciones auxiliares:

```
def es_triangulo_equilatero(lado1, lado2, lado3, angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
    return (lado1==lado2==lado3 and angulo1==angulo2==angulo3)
```

Esto es gracias a que python "compila" la expresión `a==b==c` y la convierte en `a==b and b==c`. No todos los lenguajes soportan esta característica, cuidado.

**Respondiendo a un comentario**. Si la función tiene que retornar una cosa u otra según el triángulo sea equilátero o no, lo mejor sería separarlo en dos funciones, una que detecte si es equilátero y otra que decida qué hacer. Esto es seguir la regla de *responsabilidad única*, según la cual una función debe tener un cometido claro y único.

Por cierto que para comprobar si es equilátero basta con mirar los tres lados (o los tres ángulos) no hace falta verificar ambas cosas, pero por seguir con el ejemplo, no modificaré eso.

Siguiendo el principio de responsabilidad única, yo haría:

```
def es_triangulo_equilatero(lado1, lado2, lado3, angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
    return (lado1==lado2==lado3 and angulo1==angulo2==angulo3)

def perimetro(l1, l2, l3):
    return l1+l2+l3

def area(l1, l2, l3):
   p = perimetro(l1, l2, l3)
   return p*(p-l1)*(p-l2)*(p-l3)**0.5

def computacion_rara(l1, l2, l3, a1, a2, a3):
   if es_triangulo_equilatero(l1, l2, l3, a1, a2, a3):
      return perimetro(l1, l2, l3)
   else:
      return area(l1, l2)
```

Si no quieres hacer una función aparte para mirar si es equilátero, aún puedes usar este truco para que el código quede fácilmente legible:

```
def computacion_rara(l1, l2, l3, a1, a2, a3):
   es_equilatero = l1==l2==l3 and a1==a2=a3
   if es_equilatero:
      return perimetro(l1, l2, l3)
   else:
      return area(l1, l2)
```

Comment: Es cierto, pero en ocasiones no nos interesa devolver solo `True` o `False`. Por ejemplo, me puede interesar que si es equilátero devuelva el `Perímetro(lado1, lado2, lado3)`. O el `Área(lado1, lado2, lado 3)`. ¿Qué procedería en esos casos?

Comment: Yo creo que la regla de oro es: si tienes que usar un bloque de código más de una vez, mételo en una función y reutilízalo. Si lo que necesitas es una función que devuelva True o False a si un triángulo es equilátero, la solución de @abulafia es la mejor. Si necesitas hacer ciertas cosas en base a los lados y ángulos además de decir si es o no equilátero, entonces tu opción de encapsular el código en 2 funciones es mejor.

Comment: @AleSanchez Tenía entendido que las llamadas muy repetitivas a las funciones disminuían el rendimiento, por eso el dilema de si encapsular el código en funciones para evitar duplicarlo, ó tenerlo todo en memoria para ganar velocidad, pero resultando un código más engorroso.

Comment: No se hasta qué punto es significativa la bajada de rendimiento al llamar a funciones, pero lo que sí se es el impacto en la legibilidad de un código si no reutilizas código es muy alto. Además creo que, salvo en casos muy extremos, esos problemas de rendimiento que comentas no te supongan un problema real.

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor _La optimización prematura es la madre de todos los males_ (D. Knuth) Quiere decirse, primero asegurate de que el programa funciona correctamente (para lo cual la legibilidad es fundamental). Después toma medidas de tiempos si no va tan rápido como querrías, para detectar en qué partes pierde más tiempo (esto se llama _profiling_, python tiene herramientas para ello). Finalmente optimiza esas partes, reescribiéndolas. No lo hagas al revés. En el 90% de los casos no es necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Visto el interés que despertó la pregunta en su día y ahora con un poco más de práctica, me respondo a mí mismo, para ampliar y clarificar el alcance de la cuestión. Sin quitarle ningún mérito a @abulafia, cuya respuesta es inmaculada.

Si por ejemplo tenemos un grupo de amigos que quiere entrar a una discoteca:

```
edades = {'Paula':15,
          'Alejandro':19,
          'Claudia':18,
          'Ricardo':16}

def entran_todos(edades):
    if edades['Paula'] >= 18:
        if edades['Alejandro'] >= 18:
            if edades['Claudia'] >= 18:
                if edades['Ricardo'] >= 18:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Esto se reescribiría:

```
def entran_todos(edades):
    return ((edades['Paula'] >= 18) and (edades['Alejandro'] >= 18) and (edades['Claudia'] >= 18) and (edades['Ricardo'] >= 18)):
```

O también:

```
def entran_todos(edades):
    for edad in edades.values():
        if edad < 18:
            return False
    return True
```

Aprovecho para pedirles su opinión: ¿Qué principio creen Vds que debe prevalecer, '*explícito es mejor que implícito*' o '*plano es mejor que anidado*'?

Comment: No veo que esos dos principios sean contrapuestos, más bien son _ortogonales_ , es decir, ambos puede cumplirse a la vez. En general plano es mejor que anidado es una buena regla. La anidación aumenta la [complejidad ciclomática](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_ciclom%C3%A1tica), lo que vuelve el programa más difícil de leer y por tanto de mantener.

Comment: El principio "mejor explicito que implicito" se refiere a que el comportamiento debería estar claro con el código escrito, y no depender tanto de "efectos secundarios". Por ejemplo, para una asignación condicional, python tiene un operador: `a = 3 if a is None else a`, que asigna un 3 a `a` si su valor anterior era `None`, o la deja como estaba en otro caso. Esto también puede hacerse con el "cortocircuito lógico": `a = a or 3` que funciona porque si `a` tiene por ejemplo el valor 5, cuenta como `True` y por tanto el resultado de `a or 3` es `a`, pero si es `None` cuenta como `False`...

Comment: ... y por tanto `a or 3` valdría 3. Este "cortocircuito", aunque funcione, lo hace debido a un comportamiento especial de `or`, y por tanto no es explícito, sino implícito. Por otro lado, puede no producir el resultado esperado si `a` es 0, ya que 0 evalúa como `False` y entonces asignaría 3. Lo implicito es malo porque además de ilegible puede tener efectos secundarios poco evidentes.

Comment: Y otro truco para tu arsenal pythonico. Tu función puede simplificarse mucho si sabes usar expresiones generadoras y conoces la función `all()`, que devuelve `True` si todos los elementos que le pasas son `True`. Quedaría así: `return all(edad>18 for edad in edades.values())`

Comment: @abulafia Todos los días se puede aprender algo. Gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es el operador **and**. Si tú tienes 2 funciones:

```
tres_lados_iguales(lado1, lado2, lado3)
tres_angulos_iguales(angulo1, angulo2, angulo3)
```

Y quieres comprobarlas en un único bloque if, puedes hacer

```
if tres_lados_iguales(lado1, lado2, lado3) and tres_angulos_iguales(angulo1, angulo2, angulo3):
    # Las dos condiciones se cumplen
    return True
else:
    # Alguna de las dos o ninguna se cumple
    return False
```

Pero si en caso de que se cumpla la de los lados y no la de los ángulos tienes que hacer algo distinto que si se cumple la de los ángulos y no la de los lados, quizás sí que debas separar y anidar los bloques if.

En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a los [operadores lógicos](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm).

Comment: ¿También se aplica a bloques `elif`?

Comment: Sí y a while y a for clásico. Prácticamente a cualquier condición.